# How to pass function in sql query of DocumentDB for NodeJS?

Tags: sql, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Q.1: I want to run one query on DocumentDB with user defined function,

```
 var udf = function(users, userid) {
        var s, _i, _len;
        for (_i = 0, _len = users.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            s = users[_i];
            if (s.userid === userid) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };




    conversationsQuerySpec = {
        query: 'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE @fn(r.users, @userid) AND r.id=@id',
        parameters: [{
            name: '@fn',
            value: udf
        }, {
            name: '@userid',
            value: userid
        }, {
            name: '@id',
            value: id
        }]
    };
```

But problem is that this query is not running throwing error.

Q.2: I have 1 object in documentDB with array like:

```
var student = {
     name: 'piyush',
     classes: [{
       level: '1st',
       medium: 'spanish'
     },{
       level: '2nd',
       medium: 'german'
     }]
}
```

I want to run query where medium=german, I don't want to pass level=2nd, how can I run this query?

Comment: First things first: Please separate your question into two separate questions, as they are two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. You have to upload the UDF independently rather than as a parameter. Just upsert it using the appropriate SDK call before running that query.

1. First to register the UDF using createUserDefinedFunction within the collection with a name like myUserDefinedFunction.
2. Then you can use it inside the query by name, e.g. `SELECT * FROM root r WHERE udf.myUserDefinedFunction(r.users, @userid) AND r.id=@id`

Q2. This should work (untested):

```
SELECT VALUE student FROM student JOIN c in student.classes WHERE c.medium = "german"
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer, Larry. Your's is better!

Comment: You didn't need to do that out of politeness. Also, yours had more detail around how to upload. Maybe you could add that back into my answer?

Comment: Thanks both of you, Ans.2 is working fine for me, But still I didn't understand Ans.1 how can upsert in collection, where I can do this? I am using documentbuilder NPM module in NodeJS, so I didn't get it, can you explain me more better?

Comment: There is a method, `upsertUserDefinedFunction()` found [here](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-node/DocumentClient.html#upsertUserDefinedFunction). That said, there was an issue with fanout not working correctly for stored procedures on partitioned collections. I do not know if that applies to UDFs. The work around for each would be to delete then create.